# Function in ng-bind , multiple call?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

I couldnt fint the answer on stack or google... 
**Why function in** **ng-bind call many times** ?

html:

```
<li ng-if="byProviders" ng-repeat="(key, value) in byProviderGames | groupBy: 'provider'">   
   <p ng-bind="providersNames(key)"></p>
</li>
```

controller:

```
$scope.providersNames = function providersNames(key) {
   // providersObject's length is 8
   var index = $scope.providersObject.findIndex(function(x){ return x.name == key });

   // Call more then 1000 times
   console.log($scope.gamesProviders[index]);

   var title = $scope.providersObject[index].title;
   return title;
}
```

Comment: can you please add more of your code, is it inside of a ng-repeat? is the controller being used in a directive? the function will be called twice at the very least because of the way the digest cycle works. also other factors, like the questions above.

Comment: @alphapilgrim I edit my code. Yes its inside og a ng-repeat , controller being used in directive and function calledm ore then 1000 times, but its should be called 8 times.

Comment: is any other directive or view using the same controller?

Comment: @alphapilgrim , no

Comment: i think it has to do with the `var title = $scope.providersObject[index].title;` lookup. where is this array being formed? is it from some http response?

Answer (score 0):

From the `ngBind` [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L62) we can see that this directive registers a `ngBindWatchAction` callback to change `element.textContent` whenever the `ng-bind` attribute changes using `scope.$watch`:

```
scope.$watch(attr.ngBind, function ngBindWatchAction(value) {
  element.textContent = stringify(value);
});
```

The `watchExpression` that is used as a first argument of the `scope.$watch` method is called on every call to [`$digest()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) (at least 1 time) and returns the value that will be watched (but it may be executed multiple times to check if the model was not changed by by other watchers). [This is mentioned in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

> Be prepared for multiple calls to your watchExpression because it will
>   execute multiple times in a single $digest cycle if a change is
>   detected.

In this example `$scope.getName` method will be called 11 times until its returned value become stable:

```js
  angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Arik';   
      $scope.count = 0;
      
      $scope.getName = function() { 
        if ($scope.count < 10) { $scope.count++; } 
        console.log($scope.count);  
        return $scope.name + $scope.count; 
      };
      
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="bindExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Hello <span ng-bind="getName()"></span>!
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can do to help with performance and how it affects the number of times the function is called.

First, you can add a `track by $index` statement to the end of the ng-repeat. It would end up looking like this.

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in byProviderGames | groupBy: 'provider' track by $index"
```

Second, if just displaying data and no other interaction will take place you can unbind them from the scope. So it'll no longer dirty check for changes. It'll end up looking like this.

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in ::byProviderGames | groupBy: 'provider'"
```

Superpower it with both.

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in ::byProviderGames | groupBy: 'provider' track by $index"
```

You can even go as far as to unbind the actual value.

```
<p ng-bind="::providersNames(key)"></p>
```

I'm including a code pen, so you can see how many times the function is called. Nowhere as much as you indicated above. Hope it helps. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/alphalink/pen/QqOoqL?editors=1010#0)

Unbind, properly known by (one-time-binding)[https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression]

> One-time binding
>   An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).

```js
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.exampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var exampleLookupArray = [
    { name: "Schnauzer" },
    { name: "Dachshund" },
    { name: "German Shepard" },
    { name: "Doberman Pinscher" }
  ];
  $scope.breedLookUp = function(key) {
    console.count();
    return exampleLookupArray[key-1].name;
  };
}

angular
  .module("example", [])
  .controller("exampleController", exampleController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="example">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="ex in ::exampleArray track by $index">
      <span ng-bind="::breedLookUp(ex)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```